# why graphviz dot can not open a dot file?

Tags: graphviz, dot

I am compiling a dot file to a jpg using dot program about graphviz.This is my command:

```
dot a.dot -o 1.ps
```

The out put error is:

```
Error: dot: can't open a.dot
```

This is my dot file(a.dot) content:

```
digraph abc{
  a;
  b; 
  a -> b; 
}
```

I have tried:

```
dot -Tjpg -Gdpi=331 a.dot -o a.jpg
dot -Tps a.dot -o a.ps
```

Why would this happen? How to fix?

OS:Windows 7 X64

dot version: dot - graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)

Comment: Today it suddenly works,maybe need to restart computer.

Comment: I had the same problem while I had the files on my desktop, it worked for me when I put the file into a folder and then ran the command(after changing directory to that folder obviously).

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
dot -Tpng "a.dot" -o "a.png"
```